# React Native - manage hardlinks/softlinks in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, symlink, hardlink

I need to find a tool that allows to create and manage file hardlinks/softlinks in iOS with my React Native app. Though it is a common feature I suprisingly can't find a single package that works with them (don't know if is just because of great number of materials related to package (auto-)linking in RN or else).
Can someone advice a package that can do a trick for me?

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody will face the same problem, give this package a try:
[react-native-file-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-link).